# reference to non static member must be called

Tags: c++, class, oop

Is there any way to declare the comp function here under the scope of the class declared like this.

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    bool comp(vector<int> x, vector<int> y){
        return x[0] < y[0];
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),comp);
        return {{}};
    }
};
```

This code snippet gives error :

> reference to non static member must be called

Comment: `reference to non static member` Follow the hint and make it `static bool comp(...`. It's not using any instance data or methods, anyway, which is precisely what `static` means for a class member.

Comment: Are you ever going to make a `Solution` object? If not, then perhaps using a `namespace` instead of a `class` might help.

Comment: @dxiv I am amazed to see that this worked, I remember doing this and this failed. Thanks

Comment: No. Either you didn't do this or it didn't fail. We don't use SOLVED here.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler would say that a non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object. This hint states that you must need to create an object before accessing the class members if the members ain't declared as `static`.

There are two options here:

1. Either Declare the class member function as `static` and then directly access.
2. OTOH, create an object (instance) of the class and then access the class member function.

---

The first's solution would look something like:

```
class Solution {
public:
    // Declared as 'static', so you don't need to create any instances
    static bool comp(vector<int> x, vector<int> y) {
        // ...
    }
};
// ...
Solution::comp(...);
```

And the second solution would be (perhaps you didn't want this one):

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool comp(...) {
        // ...
    }
};
// ...
Solution s;
s.comp(...);
```

Comment: You can't pass a (non-static) member function to `std::sort` so the second solution doesn't work for OP's use-case.